# Custom Logger redirect class log to appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a custom logger in my application extending Log4j logger
Below the snippet

```
public static CustomLogger getLogger(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class      clazz) {
      return (CustomLogger) Logger.getLogger(clazz.getName(), customLoggerFactory);
}

public class CustomLoggerFactory implements LoggerFactory{

@Override
public Logger makeNewLoggerInstance(String name) {
    return new CustomLogger(name);
}

/**  The constructor should be public as it will
 *  be called by  configurators in different packages. 
 */
public CustomLoggerFactory(){

}
```

}

In my code I am calling as

```
private static final CustomLogger LOGGER = CustomLogger
        .getLogger(Myclass.class);
```

In log 4j.properties i define a custom logger as below

```
log4j.appender.CUSTOM=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.File=${CONFIG}/log/mycustiom_logs.log
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.Append=true
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.MaxBackupIndex=15
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.layout.ConversionPattern=%-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [ %-5p ] [ %20c ] [%L]- %-m %n
log4j.logger.com.test.Myclass=DEBUG,CUSTOM
```

But I get error as  Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.test.Myclass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973) ............
```

Whereas when I change my initialization as

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
....
private static final LOGGER LOGGER = LoggerFactory
    .getLogger(Myclass.class);
```

I am able to see my logs redirected to separate log file mentioned in the appender.,

Can someone help me in fixing. Please let me know if you need any other information

Hi Fildor, 
 Please find the complete Exception Trace below

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testing_flag' defined in URL [file:file:/home/test/spring_defn.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'service' while setting bean property 'myclassimpl'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service' defined in URL [file:file:/home/test/spring_defn.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.test.Myclass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at com.ericsson.cac.iam.v2.authorize.service.view.IAMAuthorizeService.toggleHardLockFlag(IAMAuthorizeService.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:168)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:541)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:523)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service' defined in URL [file:file:/home/test/spring_defn.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.test.Myclass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.test.Myclass
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    ... 43 more

Comment: Can you post the **complete** stacktrace?

Comment: Hi Fildor, Added the exception trace